Issues when upgrading Betaflight for board JHEF7DUAL
After upgrading Betaflight from v4.4.3 to v4.5.1 for board JHEF7DUAL and trying to apply previously saved backup, the following errors popped up:
resource SPI_MISO 1 A06
###ERROR IN resource: INVALID RESOURCE NAME: 'SPI_MISO'###

resource SPI_MISO 2 B14
###ERROR IN resource: INVALID RESOURCE NAME: 'SPI_MISO'###

resource SPI_MISO 3 C11
###ERROR IN resource: INVALID RESOURCE NAME: 'SPI_MISO'###

resource SPI_MOSI 1 A07
###ERROR IN resource: INVALID RESOURCE NAME: 'SPI_MOSI'###

resource SPI_MOSI 2 B15
###ERROR IN resource: INVALID RESOURCE NAME: 'SPI_MOSI'###

resource SPI_MOSI 3 B05
###ERROR IN resource: INVALID RESOURCE NAME: 'SPI_MOSI'###

and OSD does not work  By the way, above seems to be a part of default config for JHEF7DUAL.
Actual resources (don't list SPI_MISO neither SPI_MOSI):
resource BEEPER 1 C15
resource MOTOR 1 B00
resource MOTOR 2 B01
resource MOTOR 3 B04
resource MOTOR 4 B03
resource MOTOR 5 C09
resource MOTOR 6 C08
resource SERIAL_TX 1 A09
resource SERIAL_TX 2 A02
resource SERIAL_TX 3 B10
resource SERIAL_TX 4 A00
resource SERIAL_TX 5 C12
resource SERIAL_TX 6 C06
resource SERIAL_RX 1 A10
resource SERIAL_RX 2 A03
resource SERIAL_RX 3 B11
resource SERIAL_RX 4 A01
resource SERIAL_RX 5 D02
resource SERIAL_RX 6 C07
resource I2C_SCL 1 B06
resource I2C_SDA 1 B07
resource LED 1 A15
resource SPI_SCK 1 A05
resource SPI_SCK 2 B13
resource SPI_SCK 3 C10
resource SPI_SDI 1 A06
resource SPI_SDI 2 B14
resource SPI_SDI 3 C11
resource SPI_SDO 1 A07
resource SPI_SDO 2 B15
resource SPI_SDO 3 B05
resource CAMERA_CONTROL 1 B08
resource ADC_BATT 1 C02
resource ADC_RSSI 1 C00
resource ADC_CURR 1 C01
resource PINIO 1 C14
resource PINIO 2 B09
resource FLASH_CS 1 C13
resource OSD_CS 1 B12
resource GYRO_EXTI 1 C04
resource GYRO_EXTI 2 C03
resource GYRO_CS 1 B02
resource GYRO_CS 2 A04

What also confuses me is that Betaflight page reads IMU "ICM20689" & "MPU6000" connected via SPI1 but JHEMCU GHF722AIO-HD 40A AIO product page reads gyroscope ICM-42688-P. Does it play any role?
Also Betaflight shows DSHOT_TELEM in disable arming flags. When I enable motor rotation in "Motors" tabs, all "E" are zero and "R" is showing some value:

ESC Configurator detects "G-H-30 - Bluejay, 0.19, 48kHz" on all ESC chips. Should I reflash them?
Other components (receiver / VTX / accelerometer / motors) seems to work fine.
Status:
# status
MCU F722 Clock=216MHz, Vref=3.26V, Core temp=43degC
Stack size: 2048, Stack address: 0x20010000
Configuration: CONFIGURED, size: 3842, max available: 16384
Devices detected: SPI:1, I2C:1
Gyros detected: gyro 2 locked dma
GYRO=ICM42688P, ACC=ICM42688P, BARO=DPS310
OSD: MSP (30 x 16)
BUILD KEY: 51bfcbffd46b666bac376d7b6ba85a47 (4.5.1)
System Uptime: 1287 seconds, Current Time: 2024-09-01T22:08:04.369+00:00
CPU:54%, cycle time: 123, GYRO rate: 8130, RX rate: 15, System rate: 9
Voltage: 2359 * 0.01V (6S battery - OK)
I2C Errors: 0
FLASH: JEDEC ID=0x00ef4017 8M
GPS: NOT ENABLED
Arming disable flags: CLI MSP DSHOT_TELEM


I have fixed DSHOT_TELEM issue by set dshot_bitbang = OFF (from here). Then rolled back to v4.4.3 (because OSD didn't work on v4.5.x) – it's better to have working OSD than latest Betaflight
